# How to get angles along a line?

Tags: graphics, geometry

What is the best way to get the angles along a line?
I have tried this for example:

```
points = Accumulate[RandomReal[{-0.05, 0.1}, {100, 2}]];
PolygonAngle[Polygon[points]]
```

However, this means I have to remove the two end points.
It's also not good in the following scenario:

```
points = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}};
PolygonAngle[Polygon[points]]
```

I hoped this might work, but it doesn't:

```
MovingMap[VectorAngle[(#[[1]] - #[[2]]), (#[[3]] - #[[2]])] &, points, 2]
```

Is there a better way? I need the angles to be in $[0,\pi]$ and intrinsic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try something like this:

```
BlockMap[PlanarAngle, points, 3, 1]
```

But you said you want the points to be in `[0,2 Pi]`, so if that means you want to include angles larger than `Pi`, then I think you'll need to decide on a standard orientation first. Maybe like this:

```
BlockMap[PlanarAngle[#, "Clockwise"] &, points, 3, 1]
```

Comment: 2pi was a mistake. I meant 0,pi so the orientation won't matter.

Answer (score 3):

```
VectorAngle[#[[2]] - #[[1]], #[[3]] - #[[2]]] & /@ 
 Partition[points, 3, 1]
```

For example,

```
Clear[points];
points = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}};
VectorAngle[#[[2]] - #[[1]], #[[3]] - #[[2]]] & /@ 
 Partition[points, 3, 1]
```

> `{0}`.

`{0}` instead of `{π}` means that the `Line[points]` does not change the direction.

- Compare with the results of  `#[[2]] - #[[1]]` and `#[[1]] - #[[2]]`, we only need to use `π` to subtract one of them.

```
list1 = VectorAngle[#[[2]] - #[[1]], #[[3]] - #[[2]]] & /@ 
   Partition[points, 3, 1];
list2 = VectorAngle[#[[1]] - #[[2]], #[[3]] - #[[2]]] & /@ 
   Partition[points, 3, 1];
Thread[list1 + list2 == π]
```

> `True`.